# PHP Runs Very Slow on IIS7. Need Help optimizing our config

Tags: mysql, php, iis-7

Am running a PHP based web app on our Windows 2008 cloud-based server. The app, which runs fine outside of our environment (e.g. a different IIS server), but is VERY slow in our environment. Based on googling this is a relatively common situation.

I installed PHP and MySQL via the IIS web deployment method...

Here's our setup:

- Windows 2008 Server Enterprise SP2 (32-bit)
- Microsoft-IIS/7.0
- MySQL client version: mysqlnd 5.0.8-dev - 20102224 $Revision: 321634 $
- PHP extension: mysqli
- Update for IIS 7.0  FastCGI
- Windows Cache Extension 1.1 for PHP 5.3

I had read elsewhere that ipv6 might be an issue, so I turned this off on the network adapter.

The app is using: localhost as its connection

Be easy on me, as I'm a bit green about some of these components... Also, rewriting the PHP app or modifying it is NOT an option. I'm reasonably SURE that our config is the issue.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue. Migrated a php app from iis6 to iis8, and on iis8 was very very slow!

Solution: In the application itself, point it to 127.0.0.1 as the mysql server name (rather than localhost). Seems that there are either resolution issues or IPv6 issues related to using the host name localhost.

127.0.0.1 solves.

Comment: Our server has IPv6 enabled and this change gave us a 400% speedup.

Comment: This is a crazy weird fix.  Worked for me too.  The PHP webpage was talking to local MySQL, changed the config to use 127.0.0.1 and I probably sped it up more than 400%

Answer (score 1):

There is a good presentation on PHP on Windows [here](http://www.slideshare.net/ruslany/php-performance-on-windows)

This [article](http://blogs.technet.com/b/jorke/archive/2008/04/14/huge-performance-increases-with-php-on-windows-2008.aspx) suggests you get the non-thread safe php binaries for Windows.  Have you looked at that?

Did you use the [Microsoft web installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/platform/phponwindows.aspx) or configure php et al. yourself?

Wincache seems like a good idea too: http://www.iis.net/download/WinCacheForPhp

Comment: I used the Microsoft web installer. How do I know whether I'm running thread-safe or non-thread?

Comment: Look at phpinfo() for Thread safety.

Comment: Thread Safety = disabled

Comment: Read through the presentation is my best recommendation

Comment: Just FYI, Wincache can lead to frequent server crashes, so I don't recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

Based on this blog post, [Fix: php mysql is VERY slow](http://www.acumen-corp.com/Blog/tabid/298/entryid/92/Fix-php-mysql-is-VERY-slow.aspx), I determined that in my case the problem is a result of MySQL name resolution. Please see [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/host-cache.html) for full documentation, but you should be able to correct the issue by modifying adding the following to your `my.ini` and restarting mysqld.

```
# Do cache host names.
skip-host-cache

# Do not resolve hostnames. All hostnames are IP's or 'localhost'.
skip-name-resolve
```

Your response times should dramatically increase. Unfortunately, you will no longer be able to connect to MySQL using hostnames and will instead be required to use IP addresses.

Comment: can you write your answer in english, please?

Comment: I went ahead and translated that for you, by way of Google. Please feel free to fix it if I misstepped anywhere.

Comment: Have you considered - i mean - FIXING YOUR NAME RESOLUTION? If that takes long the solution is not to disable it, but to fix the bug.